# How to exit from a kiosk lock down mode after the kiosk application is running as an alternate launcher application?

Tags: android, android-manifest, kiosk

I have found a way to disable the HOME button using a method found here.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />              
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />                 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />               
<category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
```

This will precisely disable HOME button because now the application is run as a separate launcher. Now, I need an exit mechanism for the user to come out from the kiosk app and then roam freely on the device. 
I currently use `finishAffinity()` inorder to exit from the app. But it's not an efficient solution as the app is sometimes comes to foreground even though `finishAffinity()` is called. Any concrete solutions for this issue ?

Comment: you can try `this.isDestroyed();
                moveTaskToBack(true);
                System.exit(0);`

Comment: Hello , thank you for the response. But I have found another solution 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46241327/4978133